# Unable to `#define` in Fortran's program body

Tags: fortran, gfortran, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

The following code is valid and compiles successfully giving the appropriate output (i.e. prints 2).

```
#define y 2

program main
    implicit none

    integer :: x
    x = y
    print *, x
end program main
```

However, if moving the macro right before the line were the variable `x` is assigned it value

```
program main
    implicit none

    integer :: x
    #define y 2
    x = y
    print *, x
end program main
```

it does not compile because the pre-processor does not perform the expansion, as confirmed by compiling with `gfortran` using the flag `-E`.

However, if I were to write an equivalent program in C

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int y;
    #define x 2
    y = x;
    printf("%d",y);
    return 0;
}
```

the macro would be expanded as expected.

I know that the pre-processor is evoked with the traditional mode by default in GCC when compiling Fortran, but quickly skimming through [cpp traditional mode documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/cpp/Traditional-Mode.html) doesn't mention anything about macro expansion in the middle of the body of the program.

What could be the reason that cause the pre-processor not to expand a macro in the middle of the program? Is it just for define statements or is it for everything else?

Comment: Experimentation suggests your problem is that you have indented the `#define`. Remove that and it works for me. Looks like traditional cpp assumes what it needs starts at the start of the line while "proper" cpp does not, but I'm not very knowledgeable here (I avoid preprocessing like the plague) so I'll leave an answer to somebody who knows what they are talking about.

Comment: gfortran `cpp` and Intel Fortran compiler `fpp` flags are mere limited language extensions. Both require the preprocessing line to begin on column one. I'd be delighted to be proven wrong here.

Comment: you should not put the defines indented and inline like that - it hurts readability

Comment: [The third page at OP's link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/cpp/Traditional-miscellany.html) confirms what @IanBush guessed -- traditional directives must start at at first column.

Comment: Ah, so it was indentation all along, I was looking for culprits somewhere else and missed that, although it was in a rather obvious place now that I think of it.